# How to export a SSHA-256 password in LDAP

Tags: ssha

I want to export a password from a database where the scheme for saving passwords is SSHA-256. The password of the database looks like `{"salt", crypt("pass"+"salt")}` and here is an example: `WbwTWc,BFWTku+j6Up2XovqmpNFATe4g9aEWWW1shFysmzx/QY{SHA-256}`.

Now I want to copy this password to my Open LDAP server. I have already copied SHA-256 password in the LDAP by using {SHA-256}+"Encrypted Password" and it worked fine.

Could anyone please help me out how can I import this SSHA-256 password to my LDAP server. Any help will be highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What LDAP server is this? If it supports SSHA-256, then the same style i.e. {SSHA-256}+"Encrypted Password" should work.

Comment: I'm using Open LDAP server. It supports SSHA-256 and also followed the same style of {SSHA-256}+"Encrypted Password". Then tried to match the password and this is matching with my "password"+"salt".